# Parse JSONArray which contains primitive and objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

I have JSON response which looks like that:

```
{
   "response":[
      "Some number (for example 8091)",
      {
         "Bunch of primitives inside the first JSONObject"
      },
      {
         "Bunch of primitives inside the second JSONObject"
      },
      {
         "Bunch of primitives inside the third JSONObject"
      },

      ... (and so on)

   ]
}
```

So it's an array with first integer element and other elements are JSONObject.
I don't need integer element to be parsed. So how do I handle it using GSON?

Comment: This is an invalid JSON document. Can you paste the real response?

Comment: This one is real - https://pastebin.com/uW9qBa6s. Sorry, can't show request cause it uses token.

Comment: Thanks for the help. See my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: This json, although valid, doesnt make sense. Do you control the API which produces this json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem by creating a custom `JsonDeserializer` and registering it to your `Gson` instance before parsing. This custom deserializer would be set up to handle both `int`s and real objects.

First you need to build up a series of model objects to represent the data. Here's a template for what that might look like:

```
private static class TopLevel {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private final List<ResponseElement> elements;

    private TopLevel() {
        this.elements = null;
    }
}

private static class ResponseInteger implements ResponseElement {

    private final int value;

    public ResponseInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

private static class ResponseObject implements ResponseElement {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private final String id;

    @SerializedName("text")
    private final String text;

    private ResponseObject() {
        this.id = null;
        this.text = null;
    }
}

private interface ResponseElement {
    // marker interface
}
```

`TopLevel` and `ResponseObject` have private constructors because they are going to let Gson set their fields using reflection, while `ResponseInteger` has a public constructor because we're going to manually invoke it from our custom deserializer.

Obviously you will have to fill out `ResponseObject` with the rest of its fields.

The deserializer is relatively simple. The json you posted contains only two kinds of elements, and we'll leverage this. Each time the deserializer is invoked, it checks whether the element is a primitive, and returns a `ResponseInteger` if so (or a `ResponseObject` if not).

```
private static class ResponseElementDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ResponseElement> {

    @Override
    public ResponseElement deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            return new ResponseInteger(json.getAsInt());
        }
        else {
            return context.deserialize(json, ResponseObject.class);
        }
    }
}
```

To use this deserializer, you'll have to register it with Gson using the `GsonBuilder` object.

```
private static Gson getGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ResponseElement.class, new ResponseElementDeserializer())
            .create();
}
```

And that's it. Now you can use this `Gson` object to easily parse `TopLevel` objects!

```
public void parseJson() {
    TopLevel t = getGson().fromJson(json, TopLevel.class);

    for (ResponseElement element : t.elements) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

> ```
> 8061
> [450602: Поздравляем!]
> [451700: С реакцией чата и рассуждениями Папани после рипа..]
> [451578: Помним...Любим...Скорбим...<br>2107 забирает лучших]
> [451371: Земля тебе пухом братишка]
> [451332: Доигрался, минус 900 экзов<br><br>R I P]
> [451269: ]
> [451242: https://www.twitch.tv/arthas подрубка<br><br>evilpapech.ru - скидка 30% на футболки!]
> [451217: ]
> [451181: или так це жерстко?]
> [451108: ]
> ```

I used these `toString()` methods, which I omitted above for brevity:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + ": " + text + "]";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this structure is the wrong format for JSON data.
You need to remove the number, or put this number as a field in the same object like the one below (call ObjectA) and consider this is an array of ObjectA.
Then everything should work well. Try the code below:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    public List<ObjectA> objectA = null;
}

public class ObjectA {
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    public Integer value;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    public String description;
}

Response response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, Response.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Reading from a file.
Example example = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\content.json"), Example.class);
```

**POJO**

```
package com.example;

public class Example {

private List<Integer> response = null;

public List<Integer> getResponse() {
return response;
}

public void setResponse(List<Integer> response) {
this.response = response;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below ValueObject format which doesn't parse first integer element

```
public class ResponseVO {
    public List<Response> response = new ArrayList();
    public class Response {
        public final long id;
        public final long from_id;
        ...
    }
}
```